# Get Geolocation information from external API using Parallel programming

Tags: c#, async-await

I am using `postcodes.io` api to get `Geolocation` information based on `postcodes`. It's working fine. But this API has a limitation that it can accept only `100` postcodes per request. I have around 300 postcodes. I am thinking of making calls to API parallely and aggregate the response after getting everything.

```
var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.GetHttpClient("GeolocationAPI", postCodeServiceUrl, _httpLogger);

            // chunks the list by 100 items and returns the collection
            var postcodeChunks = postcodes.ChunkBy(100);  
             postcodeChunks.ForEach(
                postcodeList =>
                    {
                        var response = httpClient
                            .Post
                            <MultipleGeolocationInfoRequest,
                                GetGeolocationResult<GetGeolocationResult<GeolocationInfo>[]>>(
                                    "postcodes",
                                    new MultipleGeolocationInfoRequest {Postcodes = postcodeList.ToArray()});
                    }
                );
```

`ChunkBy` extension method is returning the list of lists and each list containing 100 postcodes.

I am facing difficulty in aggregating the return response and handling exceptions if any. The `response` from each call is also a collection.

API :  http://postcodes.io/

Comment: Since it's a completely IO bound task you really should considering using the Async methods instead of trying to run it on separate threads. (Note the IO parts will in essence be running in parallel without blocking additional threads).

Comment: Thanks. Can you share some link which explains it. I am quite new to this.

Comment: @juharr OP does not run the requests in parallel anyway... It is actually good idea to run them in parallel (either with `Parallel.ForEach` or `Task.WhenAll`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To aggregate results you can collect them into a collection of results first and than `SelectMany`:

```
        List<Poscode[]> responses = new List<Poscode[]>();
        postcodeChunks.ForEach(
            postcodeList =>
                {
                   try // handle exception for individual call
                   {
                    var response = httpClient.Post(....);
                    responses.Add(response); 
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex)
                   {
                      // do something sensible with exception for request
                      // continue or abort (with throw)
                   }
               }

           // merge all results into single list  
           var aggregated = results.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Note that your code is not parallel at all - consider using `Parallel.ForEach` or `asycn` based code with `Task.WhenAll` to run all tasks in parallel.